# .app is no longer openable on OS X after copy with python

Tags: python, macos

I have this python application that is supposed to copy a .app on OS X to a new place, then run it. I do a SHA1 checksum on the file before and after copy to ensure the copy was without error, and the checksum checks out. Can anyone think of any reason why this would be? I also did ensure that the file permissions are fully open chmod 777 on the copied .app, doesn't fix it.

This is the core of my copy function in python. Which is just pulled from somewhere else an slightly edited:

```
def copy_directory_recursive(self, srcPath, dstPath):

    dirAndFileList = os.listdir(srcPath)
    dirList = []
    fileList = []
    for i in dirAndFileList:
        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(srcPath, i)):
            dirList.append(i)
        elif os.path.isfile(os.path.join(srcPath, i)):
            fileList.append(i)
    dirList.sort()
    fileList.sort()

    for directory in dirList:
        # if qItem.HasCancelled(): #If user has cancelled  the copy, quit
        #     break
        os.mkdir(os.path.join(dstPath, directory))
        newSrc = os.path.join(srcPath, directory)
        newDst = os.path.join(dstPath, directory)
        # Call itself to do move into the newly created subfolder and
        # repeat...
        self.copy_directory_recursive(newSrc, newDst)
    for file in fileList:
        # if qItem.HasCancelled(): #If user has cancelled the copy, quit
        #     break
        # Copy the file
        shutil.copyfile(
            os.path.join(srcPath, file), os.path.join(dstPath, file))
        self.filesCopied += 1
        # Feedback to the progress bar of the queue Item
        self.update()
```

Comment: Are you trying to copy between different filesystems, such as between two networked machines, or just locally on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `copytree` call from `shutils` and still update progress.  An example:

```
def update(self):
    proportionDone = self.filesCopied/float(self.totalFiles)
    # Do whatever other work necessary here to show the progress bar
    print "I'm %.2f percent done!" % (proportionDone * 100)

def progress(self, path, names):
    self.filesCopied += len(names)
    self.update()
    return []

def copy_directory_recursive(self, srcPath, dstPath):
    self.filesCopied = 0
    self.totalFiles = 0

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(srcPath):
        self.totalFiles += len(files) + len(dirs)

    shutil.copytree(srcPath, dstPath, ignore=self.progress)
```

Comment: I really wanted to get a progress bar back from the copy, so I was avoiding that.

Comment: Please check the updated answer.  This should take care of what you want, and requires the least work.  What could be better?